# What size font is the title in a default UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton, font-size

What is the default font size in a UIButton?

I checked Apple's documentation but I could not find it - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I rarely use the interface builder so that would explain why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its `System Bold 15.0`. You can check it here.

[image]

And you can change font using this code.

```
[myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see it in the Interface Builder when you create a button, is:

> System Bold 15.0

Answer (score 1):

Just by having a look at the Storyboard editor in Xcode, selecting a *Round Rect Button*, you can see in the Attributes Inspector that the font is "**System Bold**" with size **15** (pt).

Answer (score 1):

creating`UIButton` programmatically with code creates button of size **18** points and font **SFUI-Regular** . Therefore it makes difference when you create it by Interface Builder (System Bold" with size 15) or programatically.